# AUTOINCREMENT only if certain attribute contains the same value

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following specification:

> "Customer gets a free item for every 10 items that they buy"

I would create "Order_number" attribute in the customer table that tracks number of items each customer has bought.

Then would use UPDATE to update this attribute every time a given customer makes an order.

But there is a catch, this is my university project, this part belongs to insert.sql question, the file we need to submit. So I am not allowed to use any other command.

It says

> • Be sure that all of your item count is current in the database.

The first thing that came to my mind was AUTO_INCREMENT. But this attribute is not Primary key and AUTO_INCREMENT increase the number even if the order is requested by another customer.

and I am not allowed to use any other SQL statements, such as FUNCTIONS  PROCEDURESs or other programmatic MySQL-specific commands.

So how do I do this? I am really do not understand why I need to achieve this functionality using INSERT INTO alone.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the insert .. on duplicate key update

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, order_number) VALUES(1, "A", 11) ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE name="A", order_number=11
```